# JS parsing JSON. Undefined error when its defined

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

This is a JSON code that is generated on the server side and sent through websockets to the client as a string:

```
{
    "zw_ob-k7g8ahcvFzAAAA":{
        "position":{  
             "x":319,
             "y":135
        },
        "mass":324,
        "name":21,
        "color":"#5058a9"
    },
    "uTFD8dw0OiqD4ErzAAAB":{
        "position":{  
            "x":473,
            "y":348
        },
        "mass":59,
        "name":7,
        "color":"#e79448"
    },
    "CvMRJ6rEFYoU1vajAAAC":{
        "position":{  
            "x":25,
            "y":604
      },
        "mass":147,
        "name":18,
        "color":"#cef6c3"
    },
    "_e6TLrfubHqf-7esAAAD":{
        "position":{  
            "x":146,
            "y":417
        },
        "mass":320,
        "name":13,
        "color":"#ab7aa0"
    }
}
```

On the client I use `JSON.Parse` to parse this string into json structure.

```
planetsData = JSON.parse(data.planets);

for(var p in planetsData){

    var playerName = p;
    alert(p.position) //says "undefined" 
    var planetColor = p.color;
    var planetName = p.name;

    var planet = new Planet();
}
```

I can successfully get `p`, `p.color` and `p.name`, but for some reason it says that `p.position` is `undefined`, hence I can't access `p.position.x` or `p.position.y` parameters.

Comment: What's the output of `console.log(p)`?

Comment: @AlbertoTrindadeTavares console.log P works. Outputs the key

Comment: `p` is the key and not the complete object

Comment: `planetsData[p].position`

Comment: Yes my mistake was that as Andreas said, P is just a key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this line `alert(p.position)` to this:

```
 alert(planetsData[p].position);
```

And for other usages too.

Also you can add this:

```
p=planetsData[p];
```

At first of loop and now use your code itself:

```
for(var p in planetsData){
   var playerName = p;

   p=planetsData[p]; //add this line here

   alert(p.position) ;
   var planetColor = p.color;
   var planetName = p.name;

   var planet = new Planet();
 }
```

Comment: You're welcome @Nick :) I'm glad that helped you. You can mark the answer as `accepted` if it was useful.